# state management implementation in ngrx (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

### I am currently trying to build a state management representation for my screen in the image below.
In essence what I am trying to do is:

- I am trying to pull the first and last names, dob, email fields etc from the store on load up
- make a check to see if any of these fields are empty
- if there is an empty field I want to be able to know which of the field are empty through validation
- if all fields are filled then let access to the next screen
  [image: Shows field to be managed]

Here is the link to my stackblitz  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mesmpg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

-Here is my model class

```
export interface GMT{
    data: GetGMTData;
    // isDataMissing: boolean;
    // listOfMissingData: [] | null;
}


export interface GetGMTData{
    firstAndLastName?: string;
    dateOfBirth?: string;
    emailAddress?: string;
    mobilePhone?: string;
    homeAddress?: string;
}
```

here's my action class

```
export const getGmtData = createAction('GET_GMT_DATA');

export const getGmtDataSuccess = createAction(
  'GET_GMT_DATA_SUCCESS',
  props<ResponseEntity<GetGMTData>>(),
);

export const getGmtDataFail = createAction('GET_GMT_DATA_FAIL', props<ResponseErrorEntity>());
```

here are my reducers

```
export const globalTransfersStoreName = '/global-transfers';

export interface GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState extends GMT {
  error?: ErrorMap | any;
  $api: ApiState;
}

export interface State extends AppState {
  [globalTransfersStoreName]: GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState;
}

export const initialState: GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState = {
  $api: {} as any,
  error: {},
  data: {},
  // isDataMissing: false,
  // listOfMissingData: [],
};

const GET_GMT_DATA = 'get_gmt_data';

export const globalTransferInfoReviewDataReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(gmtActions.getGmtData, (state: GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      $api: getApiState(state.$api, GET_GMT_DATA, API_STATUS.LOAD),
    } as GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState;
  }),
  on(
    gmtActions.getGmtDataSuccess,
    (state: GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState, action: ResponseEntity<GetGMTData>) =>
      ({
        ...state,
        data: action?.data,
        $api: getApiState(state.$api, GET_GMT_DATA, API_STATUS.SUCCESS),
      } as GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState),
  ),
  on(
    gmtActions.getGmtDataFail,
    (state: GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState, action: ResponseErrorEntity & TypedAction<string>) =>
      ({
        ...state,
        error: {
          ...state.error,
          [action.type]: action.validationErrors ? action.validationErrors[0] : action.error,
        },
        $api: getApiState(state.$api, GET_GMT_DATA, API_STATUS.ERROR),
      } as GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState),
  ),
);
```

here are my selectors

```
export const selectGmtState = createFeatureSelector<AppState, GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState>(globalTransfersStoreName);
export const getApiState = createSelector(selectGmtState, (state: GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState) => state.$api);
export const getEmtProfileState = createSelector(
    selectGmtState,
    (state: GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState) => state.data,
  );
```

Comment: The question is how can you use all of that on your component?

Comment: Yes it is? @Andres2142. I was also wondering if I’d need to build an effect.ts or service.ts class

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you decided to try and learn NgRx. It's a powerful tool and when used correctly and in the right project, it'll bring you many benefits. But in order for it to do so, there are some rules you have to follow. And you managed to broke three of them at once, basically breaking the core principle of the NgRx. And those are:

**1. Reducers are pure functions**

This means that providing the same input they'll return the same output. And they have no side effects. Which, when you look on your reducers, does not apply.

**2. State should be serializable**

This means that the state object should be predictably saved to a persistent storage or transferred over network. We'll want our NgRx state to be almost identical to its JSON representation. And this does not apply to your functions, maps and observables within the state.

**3. State should be predicatable**

This means, that when you follow you action and reducers chain (using Redux Dev Tools for example) you'll see what is dispatched and judging by that you can tell how will the state looks after the update. In you case, when reducer calls the API you can't tell what will be the outcome.

But don't worry, you can fix it quite easily and quickly. You just need to implement following changes

**State**

Remove everything that can't be serialized, in your case Map and this API. Replace the map with Array of key value objects and API with the real response object. The one that your API returns

```typescript
export interface GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState extends GMT {
  error?: ErrorMap | any; // remove if it's really of type Map
  //$api: ApiState; - remove this, replace probably with GmtData
  gmdData: GmdData 
}

export const initialState: GlobalTransferInfoReviewDataState = {
  gmdData: null,
  error: {},
  data: {},
  isDataMissing: false,
  listOfMissingData: [],
};
```

**Actions**

Once you get rid of ill elements of the state, you can update the actions. Split them into actions that trigger an effect but don't have reducer tied to them. Let the effect to the magic and once all the data were obtained and processed, this effect can't the dispatch an action, which will fire the reducer.

```typescript
export const fetchGmtData = createAction('FETCH_GMT_DATA'); // have one action to fetch data from 3rd party something (API, JSON file, etc.)
export const saveGmtData = createAction('GET_GMT_DATA', props<{ gmtData: GmdData }>()); // and one to save them to the store
```

**Effects**

Now you can implement effects which will listen to **fetch** actions and they'll do the request and all data processing. Once they are done, they can dispatch **save** actions.

```typescript
constructor (private gmtActions: GmtService) {} // Or something similar

getGmtData$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(gmtActions.getGmtData),
    concatMap(() => this.getApiState(state.$api, GET_GMT_DATA, API_STATUS.LOAD))
    map(gmtData => gmtActions.saveGmtData({ gmtData }))
  )
);
```

**Reducers**

And to complete the chain, refactor your reducers so that the only thing they do, is creating the new state with provided payload. Nothing else, no side effects, no calculations within. Pure functions.

```typescript
on(gmtActions.saveGmtData, (state, { gmtData }) => ({
   ...state,
   gmtData
  })
),
```

This is the NgRx way. The way you did it, you've created an unpredictable state management with not serializable state. It might work but sooner or later you'll be facing strange issues which will be difficult to fix.